# IB custom font atributted text mixing typeface xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I'm using xcode 7.3.1 and trying to use custom fonts on some UILabels in IB.

Already setup custom fonts on my project, however this isn't working as expected.

When I set a custom font on a label with plain text it works, though if I try to use more then one typeface from the same family in a atribbuted text of a UILabel it doesn't work.

This is how it looks like in IB:

[image]

This is executing on a real device:

[image]

Notice the last UILabel that is defined programatically works, using different typefaces from on an atributtedtext.

Code:

```
    let plainText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....."

    let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: plainText, attributes: nil)

    myMutableString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Light", size: 20)!],
                                  range: NSRange(location: 15, length:42))

    myMutableString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Bold", size: 20)!],
                                  range: NSRange(location: 67, length:14))

    customFontLabel.attributedText = myMutableString
```

Of course I've already read other questions here that are suggesting to add fonts to info.plist, install fonts on computer and add fonts to project targets(Please don't mark as duplicated, this totally different!!).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why the fonts aren't shown correctly when cofigured via IB? Is this a bug or Am I doing something wrong?

Source available here: https://github.com/ceduliocezar/swift-labs/tree/master/CustomFontAtributtedTextBug